# Maximal subgroup of a finite semigroup (GAP)

Tags: semigroups, gap

It is a very basic notion in semigroup theory that $H_e$ ,i.e. the groups of units of $eSe$, is just the maximal subgroup of semigroup $S$ where $e\in E(S)$. Here, I want to find it by using GAP for a finite semigroup:

```
    f:=FreeSemigroup("a","b");;  
    a:=f.1;; b:=f.2;; 
    s:=f/[[a^5,a],[a^2,b^3],[b*a,a*b^5]];;
    e:=Elements(s);
    l:=DuplicateFreeList(List([1..9],i-> e[9]*e[i]*e[9]));
    [ a*b*a^3*b*a, a*b*a*b*a*b*a, a*b*a^4*b*a, a*b*a^2*b*a*b*a,
    a*b*a*b*a^2*b*a, a*b*a*b^2*a*b*a, a*b*a^5*b*a, a*b*a^3*b*a*b*a ]
```

The last code find `I=eSe` where `e` is the only idempotent of `s` ,i.e. `e[9]=a^4`. Now to find the units, apparently, there is not a certain code so, I am thinking about finding $H_e$ by a boring `for ...od` & `if...fi` loops instead. What we have in GAP is the code `Units(R)` where `R` is a ring. Is there another alternative way to find $H_e$? Any hint is welcomed. Thanks for your time!

---

**Edit:**

Regarding to @ahulpke and @Alexander Konovalov leading comments; I could do the following codes for an arbitrary FP semigroup:

```
LoadPackage("Semigroups");;
s:= Semigroup(Transformation([1,4,3,2]), Transformation([1,4,3,1]));;
e:=Elements(s);; dd:=Idempotents(s);;
l:=DuplicateFreeList(dd[4]*e*dd[4]);;
re:=AsSubsemigroup(s,l);
rw:=GroupOfUnits(re);
gg:=IdGroup(rw);;
wa:=SmallGroup(gg[1],gg[2]);
H:=SimplifiedFpGroup(Image(IsomorphismFpGroup(wa)));
```

What I did above is very elementary but I think it works. Does not it?

Comment: What is  $E(S)$?

Comment: `E(S)` is set of idempotents of semigroup.

Comment: Have you looked at the `Semigroups` package? It contains e.g. `GroupOfUnits`.

Comment: @ahulpke: To be frank, no I have not. Let me do that. Thanks.

Comment: @ahulpke: Thanks, I think I got that.

Comment: If you use `??Units` with two question marks, it returns a list of all help sections containing substring `Units`. The input would have `Semigroups (not loaded): GroupOfUnits` or `Semigroups: GroupOfUnits` dependently on whether it's loaded or not. This is a very time-saving way to search in GAP documentation, it should be tried before trying other search methods.

Comment: @Alexader Thanks many times for your time. I got the code. You and A. Hulpke put me in the right direction. Regards.

Comment: I am not an expert in GAP, but it seems that you are looking for the $\mathcal{H}$-class of $e$. There are some commands to compute it. See [this part](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/semigroups-2.8.0/doc/chap4.html#X7D14B6A080BC189E) of the GAP documentation.

Comment: @ahulpke: May I ask to look at the codes as edit added inside the body above. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I do not see an obvious error, but then again I have never worked with semigroups. You might want to ask someone who knows better (e.g. the authors of the package, e.g. @james-mitchell  )

Comment: @ResidentDementor I suggest you can post your code as an answer.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: Thanks. I appreciate you and A. Hulpke's nice  job. Regards.

Comment: @JamesMitchell: May I know your point of views? Regards.

Comment: Miss you!  Good work you keep doing on this site!

Comment: @amWhy: Me toooo. Hope to return this site to the level it was 2 years ago with help of you.

Comment: I like your "identicon" you're using now!